# Cluster SharePoint Server into Single SharePoint Server

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Please can anyone tell me, what coudld be impact of changing cluster server into standalone server.

Presently we have 2 application server and 2 front end server. Due to certain circumstances we planned to make it as 1 application server and 1 front end server.

So can someone advice me on this.

I need the impacts on it.

The major drawback will be performance issue. Apart from that, any other

Answer (score 2):

It has been quite a while since I looked into SharePoint 2010 Licensing but wouldn't this also leave you with two licenses for SharePoint that are paid for but are no longer used?

Comment: Unless, of course, Foundation is in use, then it's just part of Windows Licensing that's in play. I think.

Comment: That is very true but it is rare to see a 4 server farm built out with Foundation.  Certainly possible though

Answer (score 1):

Redundancy will be your biggest one. If you have two then your load balancer (or should) be able handle that. If your only WFE goes, you have no redundancy, and your farm is dead.

Comment: Apart from redundancy. Any Other impact